# Is it a good idea to use red color in User Interfaces?

Tags: interface, color, users, color-blindness

Colors like red and green are not visible to people with colour blindness.So is it a good idea to use red or variations of red as a user interface colour?

Comment: That's not really how colour blindness works. It's not about whether a colour is visible, it's about whether it is distinguishable from those around them. It's about *contrast* not about the colour on its own.

Answer (score 6):

You seem to be under the impression that color blind people cannot see certain colors *at all*. This is not the case. Most color blind people are able to see things just as clearly as the rest of the population, the difference is their inability to distinguish between certain colors. As long as you don't use colors that together affect certain types of color-blindness, it is not going to matter what primary color you use. My UX-lead for example, sees red and green as the same color. He is one of our built-in check if we are designing properly ;) The key thing with regards to good design is **contrast**.

[Usabilla has a great article about designing for color-blind people](http://blog.usabilla.com/how-to-design-for-color-blindness/).

---

### Some good practises for accessability

**You shouldn’t rely on color alone anyway to convey a message.**

> The best approach is to use both colors and symbols where users’
>   attention is required, like error messages and alerts. This is a good
>   usability practise regardless of accessibility concerns.

**You should limit the color palette**.

> Fewer colors mean there will be less instances of confusion.

**Contrasting colors and hues**

> Use a range of clearly contrasting colors and hues in your design.
>   This will help distinguish between elements, regardless if the person
>   seeing it is color-blind or not. Be mindful of the combination you
>   make though, because not every combo is suitable.

**Avoid bad color combos**

> You need to be smart when picking out your color combinations. Since color blindness affects people in different ways, it’s difficult to determine which colors are ‘safe’ to use in web design.

Avoid these:

- Green & Red
- Green & Brown
- Blue & Purple
- Green & Blue
- Light Green & Yellow
- Blue & Grey
- Green & Grey
- Green & Black